# Rails devise method find_for_authentication not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, methods, devise, call

I have a multitenant application, where every user can have different roles in different subdomains. There is table UserRight, which joins Tenant, User and Role. In order to find if the User have registration in particular tenant/subdomain (there is a registration if there is a row in UserRights, which joins the user and the tenant), I have overwrote the self.find_for_authentication method. It looks like this:

```
def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
    p "DEBUG"
    if user = User.find_by_email(warden_conditions[:email])
      t = Tenant.find_by_subdomain(warden_conditions[:subdomain])
      for_auth = UserRight.find(:first, :conditions => ["user_id = :u and tenant_id = :t", {:u => user, :t => t}])
      return for_auth.user if !for_auth.nil?
    end
  end
```

I use Apartment for the multiple databases and Devise for authentication (if this matters).
The problem is that when I am in subdomain, then this method (find_for_authentication) is called, but when I am in the master domain (no subdomain), then this method is not called at all upon loggin in. So the sign in form just says wrong email or password.

I couldn't find where find_for_authentication is called, by devise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method name should be 
`def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)`

Comment: I tried this way and again it is being called only from subdomains, but not from master. My user model is :database_authenticatable if this help.